# JQuery Ajax - Submit data filter before opening modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html.beginform which is used to filter a set of data when submitted and a separate form which opens a modal where those filtered results are displayed. Rather than clicking a button to submit the filter and then another to load the modal i would like to use jquery/ajax to do both from one button. Here is what i have so far...

Filter form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
   {
      <p>
       @Html.TextBox("filtername")
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Filter" />
      </p>
   }
```

Filter Controller Method ( Home/Index)

```
public ActionResult Index(string filtername)        
    {             
        var filterresults = from m in db.UserInfoes
                            select m;

        filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.UserCode.ToString().Contains(filtername)).OrderBy(x => x.UserCode);
        CheckDownloaded();
        return View(filterresults);
    }
```

Open Modal Form:

```
<form id="formid">
   <label for="platform" class="control-label">Enter Code, IMEI or Phone Number:</label><br />
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="theCode" name="filtername" placeholder="Please Enter Code" />
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Open Modal JQuery/Ajax: 
(Currently opens modal but data has not been submitted as table isn't shown.)

```
$("#formid").submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Home",
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function (response) {                
            $('#basicModal2').modal('show');
        });
        return false; // prevent the form submission
    });
```

So how can I make the Open Modal Form do the action of the html.beginform before opening the modal? (there by only using 1 text box / button to do both actions? Could someone explain how bearing in mind ive never used ajax before?

Comment: You don't? Did you debug it? What you got on your done? What's the val of response?

Comment: Hi Felipe, im not sure what your asking for ? as far as im aware you cant use breakpoints ect to debug jquery in visual studio 2013 unless im wrong ?